Maven installation issue
I have Java and Maven installed on my PC as:
java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
PS D:\> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

When I get into directory of plc4x, there is pom.xml file. When I'm trying to run mvn clean install or even mvn -version inside it's giving error:
PS D:\plc4x-0.10.0> mvn -version
Unrecognized option: --add-exports
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Java is installed as above and as this application needs JDK-11, I had configured this directory by jenv as:
java -version
java version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193, mixed mode)

but I'm unable to run mvn.

Can you paste the output of mvn -version -X here ? This will debug additional output to the console. We are interested to see the part with details of the error  from the debug output

Please check the JAVA_HOME variable... mvn --version... it should show the correct information about the JDK...

Yea it Got resolved. I was using jenv tool but i needed to set path varible
